# Why is connecting to laravel forge database giving me tunnel errors in mysql workbench?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ssh, forge

I am pretty sure this is a simple fix I think but I've been trying to setup a forge server and access the database.

My issue is when I add the credentials emailed to me by forge I get an ssh tunnel error.

My configuration settings are all there like IP,Hostname, passwords id_rsa.pub key but it will not connect at all.

Here is the email I got with the correct details from Forge:

```
Name:   rs-staging
IP Address: ***.**.***.**
Username:   forge
Sudo Password:  ******************
Database Username:  forge
Database Password:  ******************
```

All details entered are correct but the error I get it this:

```
Could not connect the SSH Tunnel
Failed to Connect to MySQL at ***.*.*.*:3306 through SSH tunnel at ***.**.***.**:22 with user forge
```

Can anyone elaborate on why tunneling might not work via MySql Workbench?

Thanks!

Comment: did you double check to make sure your SSH key was installed on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Remote connections to forge servers require that you use the `SSH` option through `MySQL Workbench` when attempting to access a database.

In order to do so, Change the "Connection Method" to `Standard TCP/IP over SSH`.

Then provide the following information:

`SSH Hostname:` your_ip:your_ssh_port

`SSH Username:` forge

`SSH Password`: skip this, use the Key file in the next section:

`SSH Key File:` Locate your `id_rsa.pub` (or other key file) on your local machine. This is the same key file that you added to `SSH Keys` through `Laravel Forge` when you setup and provisioned the server.

Then fill out the rest of the information accordingly. This should allow you to tunnel in correctly with the proper SSH Key file and access the database remotely without modifying the `mysql server settings` to allow remote connections, or adding users who need a specific IP to tunnel in.